# Animate fingerprint icon while authentication

Tags: android, fingerprint

I implemented login screen with Fingerprint for my application. It works perfectly. Now I want to add some animations to fingerprint icon while user enrolling his/her finger or after authentication, like what android OS does.

So far I found [swirl](https://github.com/mattprecious/swirl) library. It has some bugs so I preferred not using it.

Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone has same issue, I suggest [This](https://github.com/amirarcane/lock-screen) Library. It integrated pincode with fingerprint and have great animations for fingerprint icon. All you need is to start an activity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), EnterPinActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

If you just need tha animations, fork the library and import animations.